# Timeout if no user activity occurs in PHP

Tags: php, session-variables, session-timeout

Is it possible to use a session in PHP to track how long a user has not been active (no movement/scrolling/clicking) for. Without having to include the php script in the top of every single page throughout the website. For example in my login script I set some session variables after a successful login:

**login script:**

```
if ($pwdCheck == true) {
    // Starting a session now to be able to create the variables!
    session_start();
    // Then creating session variables.
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['last_login_timestamp'] = time(); // testing this one here
}
```

**Then in the top of each page throughout the website I have this:**

```
<?php
    require 'header.php'; // This includes my db login details
    if((time() - $_SESSION['last_login_timestamp']) > 10){
        echo $_SESSION['last_login_timestamp']; //nothing echo's at the mo
        header('Location: scripts/logout-script.php');
    }
?>
```

**Logout script:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: ../index.php");
?>
```

Is this safe enough to use and is there a more efficient way of checking how long a user has been inactive for, than pasting the `if((time()` statement script in the top of each file?

Comment: Hi @user3783243 ignore that, just testing things out to make sure I can pull data out appropriately from db. I'll delete that now :)

Comment: What is "active" and what is not? Refreshing pages can be considered to be active? I think you need to use javascript, not PHP.

Comment: Hi @bravemaster I see, I'll check out JS then. Active as in, no interaction/movement/clicking.

Comment: Yeah, definitely by javascript then. `setTimeout` / `setInterval` + AJAX request will do the job.

Comment: @bravemaster Thanks, I'll check that out then!! :)

Comment: Just to clear it; you can't use PHP for this because it's server side. It is completely unaware of any actions taken by the client which are not making a new request towards the server.